# about PMI(pointwise mutual information) independence

Tags: natural-language

as picture shows it says A, B are independent which means P(A,B) = P(A)P(B).
then isn't pmi always 0? because log1 = 0?
what am i assuming wrong here?[image: P]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That Wikipedia sentence is worded in such a way that the correct parse is somewhat ambiguous. Here's how I might reword the definition:

> The PMI of $x$ and $y$ quantifies the discrepancy between the following two probabilities:
>
> - the probability of $x$ and $y$ under their true joint distribution, which is $p(x,y)$
> - the probability of $x$ and $y$ under the assumption that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, which is $p(x)p(y)$

So yes, if $X$ and $Y$ are in fact independent, then their PMI will always be 0. But the definition doesn't assume that this is the case.

Comment: i am not sure i understood what you said the original sentence said " assuming independence" .
and you said "doesn't assume that this is the case"
so we only calculate PMI only when X,Y are dependent?